# Does it take/cost power when supplying in 3v to a "5v to 3v" regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a boost converter that converts 1.5v to 3v, and I have a ESP32 that takes a USB input of 5V and uses a regulator to convert it down to 3v.

If I provide 3v to the 5v input that goes via the regulator, is it the same as skipping the regulator and connecting it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempting to pass through 3V through the 5V to 3V regulator may result in erratic behavior by the regulator as it attempts to regulate below its drop out voltage, and possibly a lower voltage at the output. The regulator will also take some power for itself. It's not a straight forward option. You are better off bypassing the regulator.

Answer (score 2):

No, giving 3 from a source that has less loss than the build in converter will save you some power.

As Christian B states you will not use a buck converter to convert from 1.5 to 3v

Comment: please state why this is not an answer to the question and deserves a downvote? and I might update it to give a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like the earlier answers, you probably are using a boost, not a buck, however many converters have both built inside. For the converter, you are saving power and here is a link explaining how:

http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu32.php

Like what Passerby said, you are better passing over the regulator as if the voltage drops, you may get spikes and drops in the output. Also, it takes some (not much at similar output level) power.

Overall I wouldn't worry about power use as the board will take much more total than the small loss of the converter. If you can, skip the converter, but it shouldn't be too much of a problem if you can't/don't.